# Rebuilding opencv and ffmpeg with x264 results in java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: android, opencv, ffmpeg, javacv, x264

I've followed the readme file included with the cppjars zip file from javacv, I'm able to successfully build the libraries but when i run my app with the new .so files i get a java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError yet all the .so files exist in the armeabi folder.
the line of code where this exception is triggered looks like this

```
yuvIplimage = IplImage.create(imageWidth, imageHeight, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 2);
```

and the exception is this

```
04-29 15:40:46.610: E/AndroidRuntime(23057): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-29 15:40:46.610: E/AndroidRuntime(23057): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
04-29 15:40:46.610: E/AndroidRuntime(23057):    at com.sample.Stream.initRecorder(Stream.java:84)
04-29 15:40:46.610: E/AndroidRuntime(23057):    at com.sample.Stream.onCreate(Stream.java:77)
04-29 15:40:46.610: E/AndroidRuntime(23057):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4469)
04-29 15:40:46.610: E/AndroidRuntime(23057):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
04-29 15:40:46.610: E/AndroidRuntime(23057):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1932)
04-29 15:40:46.610: E/AndroidRuntime(23057):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1993)
04-29 15:40:46.610: E/AndroidRuntime(23057):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
04-29 15:40:46.610: E/AndroidRuntime(23057):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
04-29 15:40:46.610: E/AndroidRuntime(23057):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-29 15:40:46.610: E/AndroidRuntime(23057):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-29 15:40:46.610: E/AndroidRuntime(23057):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
04-29 15:40:46.610: E/AndroidRuntime(23057):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-29 15:40:46.610: E/AndroidRuntime(23057):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-29 15:40:46.610: E/AndroidRuntime(23057):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:978)
04-29 15:40:46.610: E/AndroidRuntime(23057):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
04-29 15:40:46.610: E/AndroidRuntime(23057):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-29 15:40:46.610: E/AndroidRuntime(23057): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
04-29 15:40:46.610: E/AndroidRuntime(23057):    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
04-29 15:40:46.610: E/AndroidRuntime(23057):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
04-29 15:40:46.610: E/AndroidRuntime(23057):    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:338)
04-29 15:40:46.610: E/AndroidRuntime(23057):    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:319)
04-29 15:40:46.610: E/AndroidRuntime(23057):    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$CvArr.<clinit>(opencv_core.java:163)
04-29 15:40:46.610: E/AndroidRuntime(23057):    ... 16 more
04-29 15:40:46.610: E/AndroidRuntime(23057): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: link_image[1965]:   108 could not load needed library 'libopencv_core.so' for 'libjniopencv_core.so' (find_library[1200]:   108 'libopencv_core.so' failed to load previously)
04-29 15:40:46.610: E/AndroidRuntime(23057):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:370)
04-29 15:40:46.610: E/AndroidRuntime(23057):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
04-29 15:40:46.610: E/AndroidRuntime(23057):    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:448)
04-29 15:40:46.610: E/AndroidRuntime(23057):    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:372)
04-29 15:40:46.610: E/AndroidRuntime(23057):    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:319)
04-29 15:40:46.610: E/AndroidRuntime(23057):    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.<clinit>(opencv_core.java:136)
04-29 15:40:46.610: E/AndroidRuntime(23057):    ... 21 more
```

I've met all the requirements needed i.e, java SE 6, OpenCV 2.4.5, FFmpeg 1.2, Android NDK r8e. The OS is Ubuntu 11.10.

I don't think the code is the problem because it works well when i use the bundled libraries from javacv but experience issues when i rebuild the libs to include x264.

What am i doing wrong? I've tried both the 64 and 32 bit versions of the NDK but same problem persists.

Comment: it is looking for libopencv_core.so. Check inside libs/armeabi if you have this library

Comment: yes the library libopencv_core.so exists in libs/armeabi

Comment: and you have in your code System.loadlibrary ("opencv_core");

Comment: based on my understanding, javacv loads the libraries so i dont have to call System.loadLibrary() for all the .so libs available, but let me give that a try and see.

Comment: It is also my understanding. Is that the complete crashlog?

Comment: yeah thats the complete log

Comment: ive called System.loadlibrary ("opencv_core"); now the link error is:
04-30 09:06:32.580: E/AndroidRuntime(3837): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: link_image[1965]:   108 could not load needed library '../../lib/libtbb.so' for 'libopencv_core.so' (load_library[1092]: Library '../../lib/libtbb.so' not found)

Comment: rebuild opencv with  -DWITH_TBB=ON

Comment: the -DWITH_TBB=ON was already there when i built opencv